Simple HTTP request in Apache Jmeter
Good evening. I'm having trouble with a simple HTTP request. I need to create a load test with JMeter. The given site has authorization. With any request, I get a 200 code without entering a username or password. Even when I intentionally enter incorrect credentials, I still get a 200 OK. How can I get accurate results, and why doesn’t the site return a 401-403 code?
Test Plan

Thread group
Http request
View Result Tree

*Http Authorization Manager

If you're talking about the "website" and not the API endpoint returning HTTP status 200 might be by design because everything was fine from the HTTP protocol level
In case you want to perform a negative test or conditionally fail the request when you're passing incorrect credentials - consider using Response Assertion
